# /xampp/lang.php not found

Tags: linux, xampp

I am new to linux(ubuntu). I installed XAMPP server in my system.. but after installing when i am using browser it shows the following error:

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /xampp/lang.php was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: This question does not relate to programming, so it doesn't belong here. But i will say, ubuntu probably comes with a web server pre installed, so you dont need xampp. If you wish to use xampp, you will have to stop the preinstalled services. Go to the ubuntu forums for more guided help.

Comment: Wherever this is question is redirected, pointing out that Ubuntu doesn't have a webserver pre-installed would be helpful I guess. Flagging as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux, you don't need xampp, linux has native packages for PHP development, called lamp (linux, apache, MySQL, PHP). In fact almost all web servers around the world that runs PHP are linux servers.

There are some easy steps that you can quickly install lamp unsing ubuntu's terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

**Note** The caret (^) at the end of the command is important.

This will install the latest PHP, MySQL and Apache2 that is it in the Ubuntu repository (depending on your ubuntu version)

You can also install each component individually, here you can find the complete steps
[Install LAMP Server on Ubuntu with a 1-line Command](http://www.sudo-juice.com/install-lamp-server-ubuntu/)

It is also a good idea for development environment to setup a workspace directory in your home folder to hold your projects and than making virtualhost files in your /etc/apache2/sites-available folder (you need sudo privileges).

More about virtual hosts on [Apache virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html)

This approach helps a lot with permissions of read/writes on your project files.

Best regards,

Comment: after following your instructions when i am entering into browser it is saying message like ....It works!

This is the default web page for this server. i am saved my file in following path "/opt/lampp/htdocs"

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.